# Making scribbles on a monochrome image

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

Imagine there's a picturebox which loads a monochrome image. And there is a need to make few color scribbles on it. I have no background with graphics. Would it be just a pen drawing pixels or something more complex I don't know.

Target language is C#. Technology: WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want would be to create a very lightweight *retained mode drawing system*. Keep track of all the positions where the user has scribbeled and draw dots/circles/lines/rubberducks/whatever at these positions in the PictureBox's *Paint* event. On mousedown+move events, call the PictureBox' *Invalidate()* function. The original picture must either be painted underneath or in the class' OnPaintBackground (which IMO is more elegant).

This tutorial should get you started:

https://web.archive.org/web/20121006140255/http://www.bobpowell.net/backtrack.htm